# How to get sender data extension substitution string when it is embedded in another DE's content

Tags: email, ampscript, dataextensions

I've currently got an extra Data Extension that I'm using to pull email content from.
I would like to be able to include a substitution string in some of that content to pull specific information located in the Sender's Data Extension.
Currently when I attempt this, it prints the substitution string as text; like %%stringName%%, instead of getting the data from the Senders DE.
Any help would greatly be appreciated!

-George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the results from your lookup in a [TreatAsContent()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#TreatAsContent) should force it to evaluate any code that's contained inside.

```
%%=TreatAsContent(@somevar)=%%
```

Comment: That's totally it! Thank you, Adam. Kinda mad at myself for not realizing that on my own. ;)